# Overfull \hbox error when indenting paragraph in LaTex

Tags: latex

I would like to indent the whole paragraph "lipsum[2]" but I am getting an "overfull \hbox" error and the paragraph goes out of the page's boundaries. How can I fix that? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title of the paper}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]
\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `\linewidth` and not `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title of the paper}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-3cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]